# Count words over 3 characters using python?

Tags: python

Thank you for your help - I'm having some slight problems with a script using python.

I have a .txt file that I would like to write a script to analyze.

```
file = practice.txt
```

I would like to read the file, separate file into words without any punctuation, and to generate a count of words that have over 3 characters and to produce an output as follows: "There are x words in practice.txt that have over 3 characters".

How do you suggest that I do this? With a for loop?

Comment: what did you try so far ? Have you made any search here on SO for similar issues ?

Comment: By without punctuation, you wish to exclude words with apostrophes like contractions?

Comment: `import re; lambda: len(re.findall("\w{3,}", open('path/to/file.txt').read()))`

Comment: I did try search other issues - I can't seem to find how to count words of a certain length. If I use the len() function, I can get the number of characters, but not of a certain length.

Comment: lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = word.strip(string.punctuation) 
Is there an easier way?
As for the punctuation, it's okay if the apostrophes in contractions are still present.

Comment: The standard Python tutorial at `python.org` would be a good place to start. It has examples that at least include reading a file line by line, splitting the lines on word boundaries, and finding the length of a string, which should be nearly everything you need for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use regular expressions:

```
word_length = 3
file = 'practice.txt'
with open(file) as f:
    cnt = 0
    for word in f.read().replace('.','').split():
        if len(word) <= word_length:
            continue
        cnt += 1
print("There are {} words in {} that have over {} characters".format(
    cnt, file, word_length))
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that there is room for significant improvements.